# Can $SU(3)$ be embedded in $SO(4, 2)$?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

I know the special orthogonal group $SO(6)$ can be decomposed into $SU(3)$ (it's a singlet plus an adjoint rep of $SU(3)$ if I remember correctly?).

More generally $SO(2N)$ can be decomposed into $SU(N)$. I'm looking for something that can be applied to the indefinite orthogonal group I'm working with, the specific case for me being $SO(4, 2)$ to $SU(3)$

For starters here, I know that $SO(4, 2; R)$ is contained within $SO(6,C)$ but that's about as far as I've gotten.

Any references to papers or just a good pointer in the right direction would be much appreciated. A full answer would of course be awesome too!

Comment: $SU(3)$ cannot embed into $SO(4,2)$ because $SU(3)$ is $8$-dimensional whereas the maximal compact subgroup $S(O(4)\times O(2))$ of $SO(4,2)$ is $7$-dimensional. However ${\frak so}(4,2)$ and ${\frak so}(6)$ have isomorphic complexifications, and ${\frak so}(6)\cong{\frak su}(4)$ (as a real lie algebra!) contains ${\frak su}(3)$, so are you asking about decomposing the complexified adjoint rep of ${\frak so}(4,2)$ (equivalently, ${\frak so}(6)$) as a complex ${\frak su}(3)$-rep?

Comment: @runway44      Yes, that is what I was wondering